# Base64 problem with jQuery Async Treeview

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, treeview, base64

In my ASP.NET MVC app I'm using jQuery Treeview with Async node expansion to build a tree of Active Directory objects. I'm encoding id's of each node with Base64 due to request length issue. For example in response for http://devel.local:49210/Domain/LeafExpand?root=source I get the following:

```
[{"text":"DC=anusiewicz,DC=pl","id":"REM9YW51c2lld2ljeixEQz1wbA==","expanded":true,"children":[{"text":"CN=Builtin,DC=anusiewicz,DC=pl","id":"Q049QnVpbHRpbixEQz1hbnVzaWV3aWN6LERDPXBs","hasChildren":true},... etc.
```

but

in some cases after selecting a node that has children jQuery instead of sending request like this:

```
http://devel.local:49210/Domain/ShowProperties/Q049R3J1cGEgeiByZXBsaWthY2oIGhhc2UIG5hIGtvbnRyb2xlcmFjaCBST0RDLENOPVVzZXJzLERDPWFudXNpZXdpY3osREM9cGw=
```

sends it like that:

```
http://devel.local:49210/Domain/ShowProperties/Q049R3J1cGEgeiByZXBsaWthY2o/IGhhc2U/IG5hIGtvbnRyb2xlcmFjaCBST0RDLENOPVVzZXJzLERDPWFudXNpZXdpY3osREM9cGw=
```

Additional '/' causes web server to generate 404 error. Why is this happening?

Comment: Dunno.  Tried mapping id's inside of your app?  Base64 isn't exactly the shortest encoding ever.

Comment: It has something to do with certain letters of polish alphabet, for example ś gets encoded to R2/

Comment: using System.Text.UnicodeEncoding instead of System.Text.UTF8Encoding solves the problem, but then the encoded strings are a lot longer. You're right, Base64 sucks :]

Answer (score 0):

take the == out of the id "REM9YW51c2lld2ljeixEQz1wbA==". jQuery doesn't like these. It should work.